# Order confirmation mails are not sending in Magento 1.9.3.0

Tags: cron, order-email, magento1.9.3, order-confirmation

Recently, I setup magento 1.9.3.0 staging environment in AWS, site is working without any problem except Order confirmation mails, when i avoid cron, mails are sending  but when i use cron mails are not sending. aoe-scheduler is enabled,
cron (scheduled tasks) are set, heartbeat task schedule is set to every 5 minutes.
All the settings in admin panel are similar to live environment,

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ? i dont want to avoid cron.

Comment: is the issue with order-confirmation emails only?

Comment: yes , only order confirmation mails.

Comment: are you sure your crons are working (you have added cron.sh in crontab)?

Comment: yes, i added cron.sh in crontab,

Answer (score 0):

The Issue Occured because of Cron to Avoid Cron Open your order.php file at

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

Just Copy the File and Paste into app/code/local/Magento/Sales/Model/Order.php

and change

```
//$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

to:

```
$mailer-> send();
```

It's working fine for me.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,But if i avoid cron , anything else is going to affect ?